# How to get list of data, particular date wise only 6 record get from each date not more

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot with security in java. I have try to gel All Event List between startDate and endDate and order By startDate but from every date only 6 record get not more. suppose in this month date wise -n no. of event is there. But i want only six record every date not more record is require.
In this **eventsListTwoDates** object i have got List of All Events.

Issue - Get Event List null

I have try with below this code

```
    public GenericResponse getAllList() {
        {
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> eventsListTwoDates = eventsDao.findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDate(startDate, endDate);
            int count = 0;
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < eventsListTwoDates.size(); i++) {
                if (map.contains(eventsListTwoDates.get(i).containsValue("startDate"))) {
                    if (count < 6) {
                        newList.add(i, map.get(i));
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return APIResponseBuilder.build(true, newList, commonMessages.findAllTrue);
        }
```

2.Query

```
Query("SELECT new map(e.id as id, e.eventImg as eventImg, e.multipleDays as multipleDays, e.startDate as startDate, e.endDate as endDate, e.startTime as startTime, e.endTime as endTime, e.eventStatus.status as status, e.paid as paid, e.fee as fee, e.passportTickets as passportTickets, e.location as location, e.city.name as city, e.myFavourite as myFavourite, e.remainingTickets as remainingTickets, e.eventName as eventName, e.passport as passport, e.typesOfEvents.type as eventType, e.eventPassportOptions.event_passport_option_id as passportOption, e.promoCode as promoCode, e.subTitle as subTitle, e.expectedAttendance as expectedAttendance)" +
            " from Events e WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY e.startDate")
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDate(String startDate, String endDate);
```

3.Response

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Record's find successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/17",
      "city": "Bombuflat",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Product Launches",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "sales",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 3,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/15",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Incentive Trips",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 5,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/15",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Incentive Trips",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 6,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/16",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Dancing",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 7,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/16",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Dancing",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 8,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/16",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Party",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 9,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/16",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/19",
      "city": "Bombuflat",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Musician1",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "sales",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 1,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/26",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Historical/Remembrance",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 17,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Party",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 10,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Party",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 11,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Charity",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 12,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Charity",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 13,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/26",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Non-profit",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 14,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/26",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Non-profit",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 15,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/26",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Rotary - Service Club",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 16,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/17",
      "status": "Draft"
    },
    {
      "passportTickets": 20,
      "endDate": "2020/04/30",
      "city": "Rapar",
      "fee": 50,
      "remainingTickets": 40,
      "expectedAttendance": "34",
      "passportOption": 1,
      "eventType": "Product Launches",
      "multipleDays": false,
      "myFavourite": false,
      "passport": true,
      "subTitle": " Celebration of World Wildlife Day",
      "paid": true,
      "eventName": "Wild animal day",
      "eventImg": "https://newsd.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Arua-to-Host-National-Wildlife-Day-Celebrations.png",
      "startTime": "20:04:45",
      "location": "Rajpath club",
      "promoCode": "NetPh123",
      "id": 4,
      "endTime": "15:30:45",
      "startDate": "2020/04/20",
      "status": "Draft"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just replace `findAll` with `findTop6`? What does this question have to do with [tag:spring-security]?

Comment: findAll is get all list of events that will not customize with each date of 6 records

Comment: findTop6 is get first top 6 record from all eventList

Comment: I'm by now completely confused what you want. can you please provide the table structure, and some example data and the desired result based on that data?

Comment: okay I will share response

Comment: suppose like Date of 2020/04/17 i have 9 record in the table but i want only 6 record from that. if that date there is <6 record is there then i want all that record - this condition is apply for all date which is get into list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sql statement like this to select the data as required in one go.

```sql
select * from (
    select e.*,
        count(*) over (partition by eventDate order by id) cnt 
    from Events e where eventDate between :startDate and :endDate
) e where e.cnt <= 6
```

Of course you'll have to adapt the column names. You might have to use `trunc` or `format` on `eventDate` to turn different time stamps into the same date, depending on how your data is stored.

Comment: I have startDate and endDate two column. In this column only date is stored not with time stamp

Comment: Then I guess you need to clarify what "six record every date" is supposed to mean, since it is talking only about one date. Still the basic structure of the statement stays valid I think.

Comment: I want six record each date wise and if more than six record is there then i want to get total of that as count

Comment: This query is get record only which is each date of <=6 Only. it will not get >=6 of each date of record